# argparse combine with optional parameter

Tags: python, argparse

If the user use the optional parameter -o then the user has to use parameter -b as well.
However, the -b parameter you have to use only if the user set the parameter -o.

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-f', nargs='?', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-o', nargs='?', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-b', nargs='?', required=????)

    args = parser.parse_args()
```

How is it possible to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Add a test after `args = parser.parse_args()`:

```
if args.o and not args.b:
   print >> sys.stderr, 'The -b option is required whenever -o is specified'
   sys.exit(1)
```